# How to adjust the legend of this chart? | AmChart 5

Tags: javascript, php, html, graph, charts

I have a chart being generated in AmCharts 5 and I would like help transforming the x-axis of my chart. so that the X axis would be composed of years (today it is generated as 2.014, 2.015, 2.016 and I was unable to adjust this, I didn't want it with commas, I wanted it to be years). (i'm from brazil, forgive me for my rusty english).

It is currently being generated like this: [currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOMLS.jpg)

and I would like it to look like this: [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0RCQ.jpg)

Here's what my code looks like today:

HTML

```
<div id="chartdiv2"></div>
```

CSS

```
#chartdiv2  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

chart.js

```
am5.ready(function() {

  // Create root element
  var root2 = am5.Root.new("chartdiv2");

  // Set themes
  root2.setThemes([
    am5themes_Animated.new(root2)
  ]);

  // Create chart
  var chart2 = root2.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root2, {
    panX: false,
    panY: false,
    wheelX: "panX",
    wheelY: "zoomX",
    layout: root2.verticalLayout
  }));

  var data2 = [{
    "year": "2016",
    "category": "111",
    "value": "20mi",
  }, {
    "year": "2015",
    "category": "222",
    "value": "50mi",
  }, {
    "year": "2016",
    "category": "333",
    "value": "30mi",
  }, {
    "year": "2017",
    "category": "444",
    "value": "40mi",
  }, {
    "year": "2018",
    "category": "555",
    "value": "80mi",
  }];

  // Create axes
  var yRenderer2 = am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root2, {
    cellStartLocation: 0.2,
    cellEndLocation: 0.8,
  });

  yRenderer2.grid.template.set("location", 1);

  var yAxis2 = chart2.yAxes.push(
    am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root2, {
      categoryField: "category",
      renderer: yRenderer2,
      tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root2, {})
    })
  );

  yAxis2.data.setAll(data2);

  var xAxis2 = chart2.xAxes.push(
    am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root2, {
      min: 2014,
      max: 2023,
      renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root2, { strokeOpacity: 0.1 }),
    })
  );

  // Add series
  var series2 = chart2.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root2, {
    name: "rent-acum",
    xAxis: xAxis2,
    yAxis: yAxis2,
    valueXField: "year",
    categoryYField: "category",
    sequencedInterpolation: true,
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root2, {
      pointerOrientation: "horizontal",
      labelText: "[bold]{valueX}: [/]{dataItem.dataContext.value}"
    })
  }));

  series2.columns.template.setAll({
    height: am5.percent(70)
  });

  series2.columns.template.set("fillGradient", am5.LinearGradient.new(root2, {
    stops: [{
      color: am5.color(0x4396d3),
    }, {
      color: am5.color(0x3472a7),
    }]
  }));

  series2.columns.template.setAll({
    strokeOpacity: 0
  });

  // Add cursor
  var cursor2 = chart2.set("cursor", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root2, {
    behavior: "zoomY"
  }));
  cursor2.lineX.set("visible", false);

  yAxis2.get("renderer").labels.template.set("fontSize", 14);
  yAxis2.get("renderer").labels.template.set("fill", am5.color("#102E67"));
  yAxis2.get("renderer").labels.template.set("fontWeight", 500);
  xAxis2.get("renderer").labels.template.set("fill", am5.color("#102E67"));
  xAxis2.get("renderer").labels.template.set("fontWeight", 500);

  xAxis2.get("renderer").grid.template.set("forceHidden", true);
  yAxis2.get("renderer").grid.template.set("forceHidden", true);

  function formatXAxisLabel(value) {
  return new Date(value).getFullYear().toString();
}

  series2.data.setAll(data2);

  // Make stuff animate on load
  series2.appear();
  chart2.appear(1000, 100);

}); // end am5.ready()
```

I would like the solution because I have a lot of difficulty changing the caption in Amcharts 5, I always kill myself, and I can't make much progress.

Comment: A correct way to do this would be to use DateAxis or at least CategorAxis instead of ValueAxis in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `numberFormat` to the xAxes:

```
var xAxis2 = chart2.xAxes.push(
    am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root2, {
        min: 2014,
        max: 2023,
        numberFormat:'####',
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root2, { strokeOpacity: 0.1 }),
    })
);
```

[More about number formatting](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/formatters/formatting-numbers/)